# Codeblocks programs won't abort after launching

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Today when I opened my laptop to make a C++ program, after I launched the program, it launched alright. I started inputing my variables, but nothing I typed was written in the console.
I closed it and opened the program again, and this time it said it didn't have permission to open the file, an error which I got previously, which meant the program was still open in task manager.
So I opened it and found my program, but it had 5 instances running! I started closing them, but to my surprise, only some were closing! 2 of them just didn't abort!
I made another program, but it had the same problem! Old programs worked fine, it seems only new once behave like this!
I tried restarting my PC and reinstalling Code::Blocks, but with no success.

Comment: If you don't show any code, we cannot tell what it does. Perhaps it contains an infinite loop and never gets to the end?

Comment: The code is irrelevant, it happens to any program, i tried even the basic Hello world program, same problem

Comment: Is code::blocks also available for windows? If yes: what platform are you on?

Comment: One advice don't use codeblock , it's heavy. Try codelite or dev-c++